# Why rvalue reference pass as lvalue reference?

Tags: c++

`pass()` reference argument and pass it to `reference`, however a rvalue argument actually called the `reference(int&)` instead of `reference(int &&)`, here is my code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
void reference(int& v) {
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}
void reference(int&& v) {
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}
template <typename T>
void pass(T&& v) {
    reference(v);
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "rvalue pass:";
    pass(1);

    std::cout << "lvalue pass:";
    int p = 1;
    pass(p);

    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
rvalue pass:lvalue
lvalue pass:lvalue
```

For `p` it is easy to understand according to **reference collapsing rule**, but why the template function pass `v` to `reference()` as lvalue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void pass(T&& v) {
    reference(v);
}
```

You are using a Forwarding reference here quite alright, but the fact that there is now a name `v`, it's considered an `lvalue` to an *rvalue reference*.

Simply put, anything that has a name is an `lvalue`. This is why Perfect Forwarding is needed, to get full semantics, use [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

```
template <typename T>
void pass(T&& v) {
    reference(std::forward<T>(v));
}
```

What `std::forward<T>` does is simply to do something like this

```
template <typename T>
void pass(T&& v) {
    reference(static_cast<T&&>(v));
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward);

Answer (score 7):

> Why the template function pass `v` to `reference()` as lvalue?

That's because `v` is an lvalue. Wait, what? `v` is an *rvalue **reference***. The important thing is that it is a reference, and thus an lvalue. It doesn't matter that it only binds to rvalues.

If you want to keep the value category, you will have to do *perfect forwarding*. Perfect forwarding means that if you pass an rvalue (like in your case), the function will be called with an rvalue (instead of an lvalue):

```
template <typename T>
void pass(T&& v) {
    reference(std::forward<T>(v)); //forward 'v' to 'reference'
}
```